# Nodejs CORS error on Base64 images with large image size

Tags: node.js, express, base64

I am uploading a image with base64 format, it works fine on small size images. But when i upload large images node gave me error like cors issue.

Please help me to fix this error.

[image]

Here is my code

```
const base64String = req.body.image;
let base64Image = base64String.split(';base64,').pop();
const imageName = path + uniqid() + Date.now() + '.png';

fs.writeFile(imageName, base64Image, { encoding: 'base64' }, err => {
   code...
}
```

Comment: That code is not the problem. You are sending from different domains, `localhost
:3000` is not the same as `localhost:4200`, install the CORS middleware on the `localhost:4200` webserver

Comment: As i mentioned i use cors already and images are save, but when i try with large images it give me error

Comment: I have the same problem. Base64 images and videos are successfully uploaded if their size is below 1MB. Anything above 1MB sends back CORS error. Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Nginx's default acceptance of file size was up to 1MB, so I expanded it.

```
http {
    client_max_body_size 1g;
```